# Trouble using hash function from libsodium library

Tags: c, contiki

I have a question related to using hash function available in the libsodium library. https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/hashing/generic_hashing

The problem is when I try to use it I get an error message: **undefined reference to crypt_generichash()**

I am also confused about the installation procedure mentioned in here: 
https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/installation

I just download the folder and place it in my code folder so I guess maybe the error is because of the reason that I didn't follow the configuration because I couldn't understand how to do it. Do I need to go to the path and then execute the commands mentioned like (./configure) but when I do it still gives me an error. As I am a beginner so I do not know how should I do it.

I am using:
Contiki (ver 3.0)
Language C
Ubuntu (16.04)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gcc: undefined reference to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426574/gcc-undefined-reference-to)

Comment: I could not understand it. How can I compile this library? Do you mean I have to use Contiki compiler to link it?

Comment: What is 'Contiki'? It should be very easy for you to use your package manager (`apt` in this case) to install libsodium (`sudo apt install libsodium-dev`)

Comment: Contiki is OS for IoT. I already tried it and then after including the header files i still get the same error

Comment: I also want to add that I have already tried <https://askubuntu.com/questions/736649/bash-configure-no-such-file-or-directory> for solving the bash: ./configure: No such file or directory error that occur when I tried to follow the instructions provided at <https://download.libsodium.org/doc/installation>

Comment: Have you reviewed this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323623/how-to-use-external-libraries-and-compile-them-along-with-a-contiki-application